# problema al mandar un objeto json por url a php

Tags: php, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(inicio)
function inicio(){
$(".boton_compra").click(anade);
$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php");
$("#carrito2").load("functions/checkout.php");
}
function anade(){
var fila = $(this).parents("p");
if(fila.find(".ma").val() >0){
    var data={"p":$(this).val(),"c":fila.find(".ma").val()};
    $("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php?",data);
```

eso tengo en el php pero si quito o pongo un isset no em manda resultado o igual si quito el var_dump no me sale ningun resultado

```
   var_dump($_GET['p']);
   print_r($_POST['c']);
   print_r($_POST['p']);
```

Comment: El primer load que tienes después del document.ready no tiene ningún sentido: `$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php");` ¿para qué lo llamas ahí? Y aquí, tienes que quitarle el signo `?`  después del de la extensión php: `$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php?",data);`, o sea: **`$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php",data);`**

Comment: porque enla pagina donde esta quiero que salga la informacion de poncarrito.php.......y siempre este en eso no so cuando se da click

Comment: peor si veo como tal la pagina me sale esto . Notice: Undefined index: p in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Homocerveserus/functions/poncarrito.php on line 13
NULL Array ( ) y si veo en la pagina donde hace load sale esto Notice: Undefined index: p in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Homocerveserus/functions/poncarrito.php on line 13
NULL Array ( [p] => 3 [c] => 1 )

Comment: Es que estás confundido con tu código. Al llamar a `poncarrito.php` sin nada, ¿qué pones?, no pones nada. Si quieres ver lo que devuelve `poncarrito.php` entonces lo que debes implementar es una petición Ajax y dentro de la función `done` de la petición Ajax poner en el HTML lo que devuelva `poncarrito.php`. Esa es la forma en que se hacen ese tipo de cosas.

Comment: y como lo harias porque hasta donde se como lo hice tambien es valido....pero igual si en el php original no sale nada quiere decir que la informacion no se esta mandando

Comment: El NULL que sale antes es precisamente porque primero estás llamando `poncarrito.php` sin datos, por eso sale `NULL`. La info sí se está mandando, pero tienes algo de desorden en tu parte jQuery. Si no se estuviera mandando no podrías ver esto en el servidor: `Array ( [p] => 3 [c] => 1 )`;

Comment: claro pero si quito el var_dump($_GET) no me tira ninnugn resultado eso me da como que nose que pasa porque el uno esta con get el otro con post y asi sale resulatdo

Comment: A ver, yo nunca he programado cuestiones de carritos de compra, pero desde un punto de vista lógico, si estás en una página comprando, no puedes estar poniendo cosas constantemente en el carrito haciendo llamadas al servidor... deberías del lado del cliente (Javascript/jQuery)  ir almacenando en un array todos los productos que el cliente vaya seleccionando y cuando el cliente apriete el botón de compra entonces sí, mandas el array con todos los productos que hayan sido seleccionados y los procesas en el servidor.

Comment: osea no hago llamadas al servidor todo lo que pone el cliente va a una variable de sesion nunca subo nada peor el problema es el que puse en la otra pregunta que cunado corre el array que va sacando al informacion la cantidad se salta puestos al ultmo subo al servidoren otra parte otro archivo

Comment: Quizá se salte puestos por el desorden del código jQuery, quizá haya funciones que se llamen varias veces o que agreguen datos nulos al carrito, etc, etc, etc. En ese código, como lo tienes, no veo que haya control estricto de lo que entra y sale del carrito. Por ejemplo, esa llamada que haces a `poncarrito` en el document.ready.

Comment: bueno pero si le quito me da lo mismo, y como podria ser mas estricto con lo que entra